# How do I get GRUB2 to correctly start under UEFI?

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, uefi

I have installed GRUB on my Arch Linux installation on `/dev/sdb1`. `/dev/sdb` is my second internal hard drive on which I installed Arch Linux, `/dev/sda` is my first internal hard drive and has Windows 10 installed on it. `/dev/sda2` is my EFS partition for UEFI. Then I ran (this I based on the *ArchWiki* article on GRUB's [UEFI subsection](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Installation_2))

```
mount /dev/sda2 /boot
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=grub
```

from within the arch-chroot I generated when I installed Arch Linux on this partition. Then I rebooted and when I got into GRUB from the UEFI boot menu, I had the GRUB minimal interface (i.e., the one that reads "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported...") only, and I did not know what to do. I have been able to install and boot Arch Linux without a problem on an older PC running BIOS, so I am rather stumped. Here is the output of `parted /dev/sda print`:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD10JPVX-60J (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  420MB   419MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      420MB   693MB   273MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      693MB   827MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      827MB   974GB   974GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      974GB   975GB   955MB   ntfs                                       hidden, diag
 6      975GB   1000GB  24.8GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, msftdata
```

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows#UEFI_systems

Comment: Attempting to boot from both `systemd-boot` and `rEFInd` gives the error message: `error: no such device ad4103fa-d940-47ca-8506-301d8071d467. Loading Linux core repo kernel .... error: no such partition. Loading initial ramdisk ... alloc magic is broken at 0x4c3f4540: 4c487920`.

Comment: Did you configure the grub after installing it?

Comment: i.e. ran `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`?

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround. I used `systemd-boot` instead of GRUB2. If you have an actual solution to the problem I will be happy to accept it, as I prefer using GRUB2 over `systemd-boot`.  Until then, however, I will use this workaround. But this was not an automatic fix, I had to work at it. I am sharing it, in case someone in a similar position finds this workaround helpful. What I did was I mounted my `/dev/sda2` partition on `/boot/efi` and copied `vmlinuz-linux` and `initramfs*.img` from `/boot` into `/boot/efi`. Then I ran the `bootctl` commands mentioned at the *ArchWiki*.  So in summary, I ran:

```
mount /dev/sda2 /boot/efi
cp /boot/initramfs*.img /boot/efi
cp /boot/vmlinuz-linux /boot/efi
bootctl --path=/boot/efi install
```

Then I created the necessary `/boot/efi/loader/loader.conf` file:

```
#timeout 3
default arch
timeout 4
editor  0
```

then I created the following `/boot/efi/loader/entries/arch.conf` file:

```
title    Arch Linux
linux    /vmlinuz-linux
initrd   /initramfs-linux.img
options  root=UUID=d26c3e60-0cfb-4118-9dec-1f1819439790 rw
```

where `d26c3e60-0cfb-4118-9dec-1f1819439790` is the UUID (determined by running `ls -ld /dev/disk/by-uuid/*`) of `/dev/sdb1`.

Answer (score -1):

Did you generate your fstab? [Arch Wiki #fstab](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/beginners'_guide#fstab)

like so

`# genfstab -U /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab`

Comment: hey now, let's not get rude.